# Was bedeutet hier "Bediengänge oder -flächen"?

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet "Bediengänge- oder -flächen"? Hier ist der Kontext:

> Nachweis der Einhaltung von Mindestabständen zwischen aktiven Anlagenteilen und solchen, die Erdpotenzial führen, sowie zu Bediengängen oder -flächen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bediengänge** (Verkehrsflächen) sind Wege, die meist der Zuwegung dienen oder im Arbeitsablauf von Personen genutzt werden. Dabei kann es sich z.B. um die "Zuwegung" zu einem Schreibtisch, zu einem Transformator oder zu einem Hochofen handeln.

Man bezeichnet diese Flächen auch als Bedien- und Verkehrsflächen. Dies gilt auch innerhalb und außerhalb von Gebäuden (z.B. bei einer Laderampe).

**Bedienflächen** können am Rand von Bediengängen liegen. Für die einzuhaltenden Abstände sind dann beide Flächen zu betrachten. Maschinenführer*Innen oder eine Laborant*Innen benötigten Raum, der nicht auf dem Bediengang liegen darf. Komplex wird es, wenn Rücken an Rücken gearbeitet wird (im Stehen oder im Sitzen).

In allen Bereichen, insbesondere z.B. im industriellen Bereich, sind diese Flächen und Gänge aus Gründen des Arbeitsschutzes und der Arbeitssicherheit mit festgelegten Abständen freizuhalten.

Comment: @Anna - ich habe meine Antwort überarbeitet. Gleichzeitig möchte ich dich bitten, einmal [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) zu lesen.